# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -60

Tags: java, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -60**

I keep getting this error, and I've been try to figure it out, but I just can't! I'm just starting java so any and all help is much appreciated! Here's my code:

```
//This method takes large amounts of text and formats
//them nicely in equal lenth lines for the console.

public void print(String a){

    String textLine = a;
    int x = 60; 
    List<String> splitText = new ArrayList<String>();

    //limits the amount of characters in a printed line to 60 + the next word.
    while (textLine.length() > 60) {

        if (textLine.substring(x+1,1) == " "){          
            splitText.add(textLine.substring(0,x+1));
            textLine = textLine.substring(x+2);
            x = 0;
        }           
        else {          
            x++;
        }
    }

    splitText.add(textLine);

    for (int y = 0; splitText.size() < y;y++){

        System.out.println(splitText.get(y));

    }

}
```

Comment: You also might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to call `substring(beginIndex, endIndex)` with the parameters:

```
beginIndex = x + 1 = 61
endIndex = 1
```

According to `substring` docs:

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is
>   endIndex-beginIndex.

This will fall in a length of `1 - 61 = -60`. That's the reason of the Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -60 ...
```

---

Here are some examples (from docs), on how to use this method:

```
"hamburger".substring(4, 8) returns "urge"
"smiles".substring(1, 5) returns "mile"
```

**Edit:**

Another error (thanks to @ichramm) is in the `for-loop` where you are printing the results. The **end condition** should be `y < splitText.size()`

```
for (int y = 0; y < splitText.size(); y++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: btw, `for (int y = 0; splitText.size() < y;y++){` should be `for (int y = 0; y < splitText.size();y++){`.

Comment: wow man, thanks a bunch! Can't believe i was missing something so simple. Really appreciate the help. (and thanks ichramm for the last tip)

Answer (score 0):

Due to substring method.

```
public String substring(int beginIndex)
```

or

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

Parameters :
Here is the detail of parameters :

```
beginIndex -- the begin index, inclusive .

endIndex -- the end index , exclusive.`
```